# Server side XMPP client for QuickBlox using Smack

Tags: smack, quickblox

I'm building a chat application using QuickBlox, and I understand that it provides SDKs for Android/iOS/JS. As part of the implementation, I have to implement a server side bot that can chat with users. Is it possible to create a XMPP client on the web server that can maintain a stateful connection with QuickBlox's cloud and act as a client, and thus chat with users as a bot? I was planning on using [Smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack), but I'm totally unsure of how to integrate that with QuickBlox.

I've seen a [python implementation](https://github.com/QuickBlox/sample-chatbot-python/blob/master/testbot.py) of a possible server side bot, but I was looking for a Java based solution.

QuickBlox doesn't provide a Java SDK. Can anyone point me to a sample code that uses Smack and talks to QuickBlox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is another one Python bot implementation with some commands set

https://github.com/soulfly/MehDoh-q-municate-chat-xmpp-bot

it works with QuickBlox Q-municate http://qm.quickblox.com 
 and you can try to play with it - it's a user with name **I am IgorK**, just register and add him as a friend.

With Java and Smack it's also possible

How to start:

1. Use Smack guide to understand how it works https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html
2. Register an account in QuickBlox Admin panel and create an application there  - use 5 mins guide http://quickblox.com/developers/5_Minute_Guide
3. Then go to Users module in admin panel and create a couple of users
4. Here is how to connect to QuickBlox Chat http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Connecting_to_server . Just build user's jid and password using users you created in admin panel and then use these credentials for Smack

that's all, should be quite simple

Comment: I tried using Smack to connect to quickblox, but wasn't successful in doing so. Here's a followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685667/xmpp-client-for-quickblox-using-smack

Comment: Ok, let's continue there